KeyError: '__reduce_cython__' when trying to import sklearn package into Django app
When attempting to run my Django app with python manage.py runserver, I am getting the following error relating to a scikit-learn module import:
File "sklearn\\metrics\\_pairwise_distances_reduction\\_argkmin.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin
KeyError: '__reduce_cython__'

This is the last line in a larger error message, listed below. I have tried everything I've found online, including:

upgrading all packages
uninstalling and reinstalling related packages
checking package dependencies are satisfied
using pipdeptree to ensure package versions aren't conflicting
restarting vscode, laptop etc.

Despite this, every time I run python manage.py runserver I get the same error appearing.
I'm using pip to install packages. Here are my current package versions in this venv:



Package
Version




asgiref
3.7.2


Cython
3.0.10


Django
5.0.5


django-cors-headers
4.3.1


django-environ
0.11.2


djangorestframework
3.14.0


joblib
1.4.2


numpy
1.26.4


packaging
24.0


pandas
2.2.1


pip
24.0


pipdeptree
2.19.1


psycopg
3.1.18


psycopg2-binary
2.9.9


python-dateutil
2.9.0.post0


pytz
2024.1


scikit-learn
1.4.2


scipy
1.13.0


six
1.16.0


sqlparse
0.4.4


stringcase
1.2.0


threadpoolctl
3.5.0


typing_extensions
4.9.0


tzdata
2024.1



Interestingly from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer causes no issues, but from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances is the line causing the issue.
Please help! Have been stuck on this for a few days now.
Full error message:
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:userpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:userpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 519, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:userpath\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path("page/", include("shopping_list.urls")),
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:userpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:userpath\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import my_api
  File "C:userpath\my_api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import cluster
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ._unsupervised import (
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ..pairwise import _VALID_METRICS, pairwise_distances, pairwise_distances_chunked
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 43, in <module>
    from ._pairwise_distances_reduction import ArgKmin
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    from ._dispatcher import (
  File "C:userpath\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_dispatcher.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._argkmin import (
  File "sklearn\\metrics\\_pairwise_distances_reduction\\_argkmin.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin
KeyError: '__reduce_cython__'

